# IIS dynamic compression and HttpHandlers

Tags: iis, compression, httphandler

Does anyone know if it's possible to use [IIS Dynamic Content Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681(WS.10).aspx) to compress the output of an [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) (.ashx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Make sure that the right content type is in the list of the dynamic content types (they are set on a server level, you can get to them through IIS settings editor, in system.webServer\httpCompression, dynamicTypes collection). If the type is not in the list, you'll be able to see DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS Reason="NO_MATCHING_CONTENT_TYPE" when you do [FREB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). Don't forget to restart the application pool.